# Постобработка добавленных записей

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть три таблицы

```
CREATE TABLE A (
  ID NUMBER,
  B_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
  ...........
  CONSTRAINT FK_A_B FOREIGN KEY (B_ID)
    REFERENCES B (ID) ENABLE VALIDATE,
  CONSTRAINT PK_A
  PRIMARY KEY (ID) ENABLE VALIDATE
)

CREATE TABLE B (
  ID NUMBER,
  TYPE NUMBER NOT NULL,
  ...........
  CONSTRAINT PK_B
  PRIMARY KEY (ID) ENABLE VALIDATE
)

CREATE TABLE C (
  ID NUMBER,
  A_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
  DATA NUMBER NOT NULL,
  ...........
  CONSTRAINT FK_C_A FOREIGN KEY (A_ID)
    REFERENCES A (ID) ENABLE VALIDATE,
  CONSTRAINT PK_A
  PRIMARY KEY (ID) ENABLE VALIDATE
)
```

(пара `A_ID`, `DATA` не уникальна и может повторяться до трех раз)

Нужно после (или во время) импорта данных в эти таблицы для всех **новых** записей вставить записи в такую таблицу

```
CREATE TABLE D (
  ID NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  A_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
  DATA NUMBER,
  CONSTRAINT FK_D_A FOREIGN KEY (A_ID)
    REFERENCES A (ID) ON DELETE CASCADE ENABLE VALIDATE,
  CONSTRAINT PK_D
  PRIMARY KEY (ID) ENABLE VALIDATE,
  CONSTRAINT UNQ_D
  UNIQUE (A_ID, "DATA") ENABLE VALIDATE
)
```

Но вставить по хитрому алгоритму.

1. Для каждой новой записи в таблицах `A` и `C` через таблицу `A`, получить значение `B.TYPE`
2. Для этого значения вызвать функцию `my_func`, которая вернет 0 или 1
3. Если функция вернула 0, то выполнить запрос

   ```
   INSERT INTO D (A_ID, DATA)
     SELECT ID, NULL FROM A WHERE ID = current_id;
   ```
4. Если функция вернула 1, то выполнить такой запрос

   ```
   INSERT INTO D (A_ID, DATA)
     SELECT DISTINCT A_ID, DATA FROM C WHERE A_ID = current_a_id;
   ```

Функция `my_func` имеет вид

```
CREATE FUNCTION my_func (in_type IN NUMBER)
RETURN NUMBER
DETERMINISTIC
IS
BEGIN
  IF (in_type IN (5, 13, 17, 20, 65, 79)) THEN
    RETURN 1;
  ELSE
    RETURN 0;
  END IF;
END;
```

Как бы эту задачу решить поэффективней? Учитывая, что возможна ситуация когда импорт одних и тех же данных может происходить параллельно (если данные уже есть, то ничего делать не нужно. Вернее нужно обновить другие поля, но к этому алгоритму они не относятся). Задача осложняется тем, что возможна ситуация (хотя она и маловероятна) когда к существующим записям в `С`, которые ссылаются на одну запись из `A` добавляются еще записи, ссылающиеся на эту же запись и для `my_func() = 1` нужно будет добавить записи в `D`

В одном пакете импорта могут прийти тысячи записей в `A` (не факт, что все они будут новыми). На каждую запись из `A` могут ссылаться до 10 записей из `C`

Comment: А импорт чем выполняется?

Comment: Ерунда какая-то... *Если функция вернула X, то выполнить запрос* - вставить в таблицу D **все** записи из А или С? Догадываюсь, что как-то нужно коррелироваться по A_ID на вставляемую запись... тогда *Задача осложняется тем, что* - есть ещё хуже - вставляем в А, функция вернула 1, лезем в С, а там шиш такого A_ID...

Comment: В чем собственно вы видите какие либо проблемы ? "_если данные уже есть - ничего не делать_", так и не делайте, insert и не будет пытаться пройти, значит больше ничего происходить и не будет. А по поводу остального, нет никакого "оптимального" пути, есть только единственный существующий, триггера на таблицах A и C должны отработать эти ситуации и выполнить действия. Если функция my_func детерменированна и при этом долго выполняется, возможно стоит где то хранить готовые значения 0 и 1 для всех B.TYPE. P.S. хотя есть отличная оптимизация, исходя из приведенной структуры таблица D вообще не нужн

Comment: @Akina не **все**, а текущую просматриваемую

Comment: @Viktorov Внешней самописной утилитой. Утилита для вставки/обновления вызывает процедуры БД

Comment: @Mike Функция детерминирована и проста. На определенные TYPE вернуть 1, на остальные 0. Таблица D нужна, т.к. именно по этой таблице будут строиться отчеты и в кросс-таблицу, связанную с D будут сыпаться данные с оборудования. Данных много, сыпятся часто. Проблему вижу, что в AFTER INSERT триггере для `D` будут вхолостую выполнятся выборки, т.к. в 90% случаев окажется, что в `D` уже есть такая запись. Или на эффективность выборки по первичному ключу, даже если их много, можно забить? Смотрел в сторону временных таблиц, но ничего толкового не придумал

Comment: А как вы предполагаете снизить количество проверок ? Если данные в A/C добавлены, то все равно в какой то момент проверить были такие данные или нет придется. если мы не сделаем это в момент вставки, нам то же самое придется сделать позже. Вот если у вас есть задача сделать сам insert как можно быстрее, а информация в таблице D нужна совершенно не срочно, то можно что то пробовать делать. только суммарно ресурсов оно съест скорее всего больше, просто в другое время. И что то мне не очень нравится ваша фраза "_будут вхолостую выполнятся выборки_", надеюсь вы не делаете проверки отдельным select

Comment: И откуда "90% данных, которые есть" ? Если что то добавляем в A, то в D этого точно еще нет. Если в C ... там (в C) действительно нет уникальности на A_ID, DATA ?

Comment: Насколько объёмны таблицы А и С? *Функция детерминирована и проста. На определенные TYPE вернуть 1, на остальные 0.* Почему это оформлено функцией, а не таблицей?

Comment: @Mike Нет. Уникальности нет и не предполагается. Более того Количество дублей `A_ID, DATA` будет три (или не будет вообще). Зависит от того же "TYPE". Я даже сомневаюсь, что на вставку в A нужно что-то делать. A без C не бывает. А на вставку в C все равно нужны проверки по доставанию "TYPE"

Comment: @Akina Можно и таблицей - не принципиально. Это что-то даст?
 Функцию удобнее вызывать. Там код `IF (in_type IN (.......)) THEN RETURN 1 ELSE RETURN 0`

Comment: Тогда возможная оптимизация, если дубли по A_ID, DATA приходят боле менее в одно время, где то помнить уникальные пришедшие A_ID, DATA, что бы для каждого заново не проверять тип и т.п. Либо запоминание всего и выборка перед проверками distinct. но само такое запоминание, выборка с группировкой и последующее удаление, то же потребуют некоторых дополнительных ресурсов и я сильно сомневаюсь, что такие ресурсы будут сильно меньше, чем затраченные на троекратную проверку C->A->B-Type. В итоге имеем сильное усложнение логики, а выигрыша не заметно...

Comment: Да у Вас тут всё - загадка... Зачем понадобилась связанная таблица В, если ссылка на неё имеет такой же размер, как и доставаемые оттуда данные - и что бы в таблице А не держать сразу значение? а не-выход за допустимые значения проверять констрейнтом на поле со статическим или из той же таблицы В списком, если он обширен или изменяем. А коли так - то и это самое myfunc=0/1 можно не считать, а держать там же, в таблице А. Скажем, в вычислимом поле.

Comment: *Можно и таблицей - не принципиально. Это что-то даст?* ну в функции-то мы имеем прямой скан списка, тогда как в таблице могли бы проверять по индексу...

Comment: @Mike все записи с одним A_ID приходят в одной транзакции. `где-то хранить данные` - вот я и говорю о временной таблице

Comment: @Akina В таблице `B` есть еще поля. В `B` могут быть разные записи с одним TYPE

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Во временной нельзя. Если между попаданием записи в БД и записью в D из временной таблицы что то произойдет с экземпляром, то у нас будет рассогласование между D и остальными таблицами. проще тогда уж сделать запись в D не триггерами, а из функции импорта. которая может сама обнаружить дубли в данных и писать меньше. или выполнять запись в D группы данных в пределах одного MERGE (где в подзапросе можно и distinct написать)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итого остановился на AFTER INSERT триггере для `C`

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_C_AI AFTER INSERT ON C
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  var_action NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT
    my_func(B."TYPE")
  INTO
    var_action
  FROM
    A
    LEFT JOIN B ON (
      A.B_ID = B.ID
    )
  WHERE
    A.ID = :NEW.A_ID;

  IF (var_action = 1) THEN
    MERGE INTO
      D
    USING (
      SELECT
        :NEW.A_ID AS A_ID,
        :NEW.DATA AS DATA
      FROM
        dual
    ) sub
    ON (
      D.A_ID = sub.A_ID AND
      D.DATA = sub.DATA
    ) WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (
      A_ID,
      DATA
    ) VALUES (
      :NEW.A_ID,
      :NEW.DATA
    );
  ELSE
    MERGE INTO
      D
    USING (
      SELECT
        :NEW.A_ID AS A_ID
      FROM
        dual
    ) sub
    ON (
      D.A_ID = sub.A_ID
    ) WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (
      A_ID,
      DATA
    ) VALUES (
      :NEW.A_ID,
      NULL
    );
  END IF;
END;
```